# how to get the filename along with absolute path to the file, whenever a new file is created using inode in linux?

Tags: linux, perl, centos6, file-management, inode

I doing some experiments with my linux OS (CentOS) and I want to track all the tool logs created under the same environment, tool generates the respective logs (.log extn) for tracking these changes I wrote a perl watcher which actually monitoring the directory that I set and when the new file is created it will show at the output but This is consuming a lot of memory and CPU utilization as i have set 2sec as the sleep period.

My QUESTION "Is there any better of way doing this ?" I thought of using inode table for tracking all the changes in the system. can this solve my issue ? and if yes then could please let us know the solution towards the same ?

Comment: zdim, it is great to hear about those modules. Vikas, not sure if you are looking for a generic file system monitor that zdim is suggesting.  If you can share your Perl code, probably we can figure out why it is consuming so much memory & cpu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you want to monitor a directory for changes.  This is a complex job, but for which there are good modules. The easiest one to recommend is probably [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm)

> This module implements an interface to the Linux 2.6.13 and later Inotify file/directory change notification system.

This seems to be along the lines of what you wanted.

Any such monitor needs additional event handling. This example uses [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.13/lib/AnyEvent.pm).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use AnyEvent;
use Linux::Inotify2;

my $dir = 'dir_to_watch';

my $inotify = Linux::Inotify2->new  or die "Can't create inotify object: $!";

$inotify->watch( $dir, IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE, sub {
    my $e = shift;
    my $name = $e->fullname;
    say "$name modified" if $e->IN_MODIFY;    # Both show the new file
    say "$name created"  if $e->IN_CREATE;    # but see comments below
});

my $inotify_w = AnyEvent->io (
    fh => $inotify->fileno, poll => 'r', cb => sub { $inotify->poll }
);

1 while $inotify->poll;
```

If you only care about *new* files then you only need one constant above. 
For both types of events the `$name` has the name of the new file. From `man inotify` on my system

> ... the `name` field in the returned `inotify_event` structure identifies the name of the file within the directory.

The `inotify_event` structure is suitably represented by a `Linux::Inotify2::Watcher` object.

Using `IN_CREATE` seems to be an obvious solution for your purpose. I tested by creating two files, with two redirected `echo` commands separated by semi-colon on the same command line, and also by `touch`-ing a file. The written files are detected as separate events, and so is the `touch`-ed file.

Using `IN_MODIFY` may also work since it monitors (in `$dir`)

> ... any file system object in the watched object (always a directory), that is files, directories, symlinks, device nodes etc. ...

As for tests, both files written by `echo` as above are reported, as separate events. But a `touch`-ed file is *not* reported, since data didn't change (the file wasn't written to).

Which is better suited for your need depends on details. For example, a tool may open a log file as it starts, only to write to it much later. The two ways above will behave differently in that case. All this should be investigated carefully under your specific conditions.

We may think of a race condition, since while the code executes other file(s) could slip in. But the module is far better than that and it does report new changes after the handler completes. I tested by creating files while that code runs (and sleeps) and they are reported.

Some other notable frameworks for event-driven programming are [POE](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-1.367/lib/POE.pm) and [IO::Async](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/IO-Async-0.70/lib/IO/Async.pm).

The [File::Monitor](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/File-Monitor-1.00/lib/File/Monitor.pm) does this kind of work, too.

Comment: In my script I am using the File::Monitor to watch the files but if I run my script more than 3 days , then it will consume more CPU usage. I want a way by which we can track the inode of the linux so that when a new inode is created I can easily get the file name using that inode. So, Is there any way to track a inode

Comment: @vikaschib Thank you for feedback!  This is why I firstly recommended _this module_ -- it implements the `inotify` system, which is precisely what you ask about. I would not recommend doing that by hand (except for fun.)  As for increased CPU usage ... sounds like it may be that module's problem?  I'd suggest: (1) Try this one (2) Can you schedule the script to not run for that long continuously? Perhaps exit and restart (by a cron job?) (3) If the problem persists, post another question, as that  is something else.